# GWT, Gradle, multiple SLF4J bindings error

Tags: gradle, gwt, slf4j

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in
[jar:file:/home/user/.IntelliJIdea2017.2/system/gwt/Lexical-Internal.cce6de70/rfiWebapp.1cb4267e/run/www/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in
[jar:file:/home/user/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.12/485f77901840cf4e8bf852f2abb9b723eb8ec29/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation. 
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] 
Dec 14, 2017 2:24:38 PM org.mongodb.morphia.logging.MorphiaLoggerFactory choose LoggerFactory
INFO: LoggerImplFactory set to org.mongodb.morphia.logging.jdk.JDKLoggerFactory
```

Why there is something in `/.IntelliJIdea2017.2/`... ?

How to exclude that part?

The other one in `/.gradle/`... seems in my external library.

Comment: And why have you not looked at the link provided?

Comment: OK, since it is just a warning. I'd ignore it for now.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar` in your classpath.

If you can either remove `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar` from `WEB-INF/lib` folder or exclude the dependency (find it from the dependency tree and exclude it) from your `build.gradle`, it should do the job.